# Tessellate polygons (linear rings) with altitudemode relativeToGround

Tags: kml, google-earth, google-earth-plugin

The [Google Earth KML documentation](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#tessellate) seems to say flat-out you cannot do this, but I want to have tessellated polygons (linear rings) such that the interior of the polygon follows the terrain as it would in `<altitudeMode>clampToGround</altitudeMode>`.  However, I want these polygons to be "floating" like they would be with `<altitudeMode>relativeToGround</altitudeMode>`

Has anyone encountered this or found a workaround?

Comment: Have you tried anything in the KML yet with any kind of result?

Comment: @Matthew, I have tried the following  in kml to force tessellation for one of the polygons (to no avail):  

    <Polygon>  
    <altitudeMode>relativeToGround</altitudeMode>  
    <outerBoundaryIs>  
    <LinearRing>  
    <tessellate>1</tessellate>  
    <coordinates>  
    ...  
    </coordinates>  
    </LinearRing>  
    </outerBoundaryIs>  
    </Polygon>

Comment: In case anyone is interested I have added a request for an enhancement [Issue 432](http://code.google.com/p/kml-samples/issues/detail?id=432)

Comment: Just discovered this. Crucial omission. I have added my vote, and a comment, to issue 432.